# <ALT+H> hotkey doesn't work with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, hotkeys, kali-linux

I can't bind command `"cursorLeft"` to `"alt+h"` . This is my setting file `keybindings.json`

```
[    { "key": "alt+h",                  "command": "cursorLeft",
        "when": "textInputFocus" },
    { "key": "alt+l",                  "command": "cursorRight",
        "when": "textInputFocus" },
    { "key": "alt+k",                  "command": "cursorUp",
        "when": "textInputFocus" },
    { "key": "alt+j",                  "command": "cursorDown",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }]
```

Other three hotkeys work properly. If I change hotkey `<alt+h>` to any other combination, It works too. My operation system is `Kali Linux`. It doesn't work with Windows as well. I have checked it. Is there anything I could have missed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found solution. I have no idea why, but If we replace `"alt+h"` with `"alt+H"`, it will work.
But still, final result isn't good enough. There are various side effects and freezes. I think I need another key instead of `alt`.

Comment: for me in kUbuntu i need workaround to get Path using Ctrl+Shift+C. needed the python autoKey for dirty workaround. same prob with some other hotKeys